# Select categories, subcategories and number of topics in 1 query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
        c.frm_category_id,
        c.name,
        c.slug,
        s.frm_category_id,
        s.name,
        s.slug,
        IFNULL(COUNT(t.frm_topic_id),0)
FROM
        frm_categories AS c
LEFT JOIN
        frm_categories AS s
    ON
        c.frm_category_id = s.parent_frm_category_id
LEFT JOIN
        frm_topics AS t
    ON
        s.frm_category_id = t.frm_category_id                       
WHERE
        c.active = 1
    AND
        s.active = 1
ORDER BY
        c.frm_category_id ASC,
        s.frm_category_id ASC
```

What I want to accomplish is the following:

I want to select ALL parent categories (even if they don't have subcategories), and I want to count all the topics in every subcategory (a topic can only be posted in a subcategory, not in a category).

This query works half: it only selects the categories with subcategories, and only the subcategories which have topics in it.

Can someone fix this problem? Or give me a useful tip to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miss group by logic with the frm_topics table, and better put the filter in on clause instead of where clause during outer join.

```
SELECT
        c.frm_category_id,
        c.name,
        c.slug,
        s.frm_category_id sub_cate_id,
        s.name,
        s.slug,
        IFNULL(tpc_count,0)
FROM
        frm_categories AS c
LEFT join 
        frm_categories AS s
    on 
        c.frm_category_id = s.parent_frm_category_id and c.active = 1 and s.active = 1
LEFT JOIN
(select frm_category_id, count(1) tpc_count from 
        frm_topics group by frm_category_id)AS t
    ON
        s.frm_category_id = t.frm_category_id
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6f68/6)

Comment: My apologies for asking, but how can I do this exactly?

Comment: This does not work. Active means "is the category/subcategory active" yes (1) or no (0). I still get the same result unfortunately. Anyway, thank you for your effort, amow.

Comment: @yesterday changed my answer and also add sql fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I have now the following query:

```
SELECT
            c.frm_category_id,
            c.name,
            c.slug,
            s.frm_category_id,
            s.name,
            s.slug
FROM
            frm_categories AS c
LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT
                frm_category_id,
                parent_frm_category_id,
                name,
                slug
        FROM
                frm_categories
        WHERE
                parent_frm_category_id != 0
) AS s
        ON
            c.frm_category_id = s.parent_frm_category_id            
WHERE
            c.parent_frm_category_id = 0
ORDER BY
            c.frm_category_id ASC
```

It works for a part: I now get ALL the categories, the ones WITH subcategories and the ones WITHOUT categories.

The only thing i want to add now is to count all the topics in each SUBCATEGORY

table: topics

frm_topic_ic, frm_category_id, title